# What's the significance of the *initially* displayed data when launching atop?

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring, atop

I've just started using atop to try to get to the bottom of some system bottlenecks.

I've found https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop which is very useful and explains most of what it does just fine.

What I'm curious about is what data atop shows **when you very first launch it**.

I ask because *every* time I launch it I have a red line that tells me `swout 311826`, and a cyan line telling me disk usage is at 67%.

After 10 seconds they both clear and go back to low levels (or in the case of the PAG line disappears).

Is it telling me the worst statistic from the past hour?  Day?  Ever?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial display of `atop` contains metrics accumulated/averaged since the last reboot.

In particular `swout` is a sum of all swapouts since the last reboot. The disk busy `67%` is an average (ouch!).

If you have historical data, the initial display of `atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_20180613` contains metrics accumulated/averaged since the boot until 2018-06-13 00:00:00.

Comment: I only just installed it so I'm assuming those numbers are since installed rather than since the last reboot?

Comment: These counters are maintained even when `atop` is not installed. It's only a reporting tool. @Codemonkey